# Recursive block T4 template

Tags: templates, t4

I have a function named IterateThroughChildren() and I want to write the code to emit the code from inside of that function.

Normally the code block is included inside <# #> and custom functions are included inside <#+ #>, we emit our code inside <#= #> block. What if I want to recursively execute the above mentioned function and based on some logic I want to emit the code i.e.

e.g

```
<#  
    //Code to get child and parent data  
    IterateThroughChildren(object child, object parent);  
 #>  

<#+  
void IterateThroughChildren(object c, object p)  
{  
 if(c is abc)  
 {  
  if(p is def)  
  {  
   //emit some code here i.e WriteLine(SomeThing); ?????  
   foreach (var item in def.Item)  
   {  
    IterateThroughChildren(item, def);  
   }  

  }  
 }  

 .
 .
 .

 //and so on

}  

 #>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the class feature blocks in T4, i.e. **<#+ #>**, then that code becomes part of the underlying class that generates the template's output file.  In Visual Studio 2008, that underlying class derives from the abstract class **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTransformation**.

Thus, you can write directly to the output stream by using the inherited **Write()** or **WriteLine()** methods.  For example, in your code:

```
    <#
    //Code to get child and parent data
    IterateThroughChildren(object child, object parent);
    #>

    <#+
    void IterateThroughChildren(object c, object p)
    {
    if(c is abc)
    {
    if(p is def)
    {
    //emit some code here i.e WriteLine(SomeThing); ?????
    this.WriteLine(SomeThing); // writes SomeThing to the output file
    foreach (var item in def.Item)
    {
    IterateThroughChildren(item, def);
    }

    }
    }

. . .

//and so on

}

#>
```

where **this.WriteLine(SomeThing)** is the only thing I added.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question, but still wanted to share: you can avoid using the `Write()` and `WriteLine()` methods altogether by using an `Action<>`:

```
<#
    Action<object,object> IterateThroughChildren = null; // null to avoid compile-time error
    IterateThroughChildren = delegate(object c, object p)
    {
        if(c is abc)
        {
            if(p is def)
            {
#>
// Emit some code here. No WriteLine() or Write() needed!
<#
            }

            foreach (var item in def.Item)
            {
                IterateThroughChildren(item, def);
            }
        }
    }

    //Code to get child and parent data
    IterateThroughChildren(child, parent);
#>
```

The buildup and teardown of the delegate creates somewhat ugly code, but using the `<#...#>` syntax in between has many advantages.

(I know the sample is bad code, but I tried to mirror the accepted answer's pseudo code as good as possible.)